# Proof that the superset of a Dedekind infinite set is also Dedekind infinite?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I prove that any superset of an Dedekind-infinite set is also Dedekind-infinite? Or a link to a proof? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is Dedekind-infinite, then there is some $B\subsetneq A$ and $f\colon A\to B$ which is a bijection.

Let $C\supseteq A$, define $$g(c)=\begin{cases} f(c) & c\in A\\ c & c\notin A\end{cases}$$

Then $g\colon C\to B\cup(C\setminus A)$ is a bijection with a proper subset of $C$.

Comment: That works! Thanks for your help, Asaf. I will upload my formal proof (467 lines) to my website when I am able and post the link here.